# Custom Generic Validation Annotation c#

Tags: c#, generics, annotations

I need to write a generic validation annotation that checks if all elements of a collection are unique based on some property of the objects in the collection.

For example, it would need to validate that all task names in a list of tasks are unique:

```
class Task
{
   public string TaskName {get; set;}
   public bool TaskIsComplete {get; set;}
   ...
}

[UniqueElementsRequired(ErrorMessage = "Task names must be unique")]
List<Task> TaskList {get; set;}
```

The problem is that it must be generic so I don't know how to specify what properties to use as the deciding factor in what constitutes "unique".

Basically I'd want to do something like:

```
[UniqueElementsRequired(TaskList.Select(x => x.TaskName), ErrorMessage = "Task names must be unique")]
List<Task> TaskList {get; set;}
```

Where I could just use the list of task names. However I can't find a way to pass in an additional list like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and experimentation I found a way to access the properties of objects stored in the collection I'm trying to validate from within the validation annotation. The trick is the constructor and getting a hold of the PropertyInfo you want. It was a little tricky to keep it generalized.

```
public class UniqueElementsRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the UniqueElementsRequiredAttribute class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeOfCollectionElements">Type of the elements in the collection. Leave as null if testing the elements directly rather than one of their properties.</param>
    /// <param name="nameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness">Name of element property desired to be unique. Leave as null if testing the elements directly rather than one of their properties. MUST BE EXACT.</param>
    public UniqueElementsRequiredAttribute(Type typeOfCollectionElements = null, string nameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness = null)
    {
        NameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness = nameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness;
        TypeOfCollectionElements = typeOfCollectionElements;
    }

    private string NameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness { get; set; }

    private Type TypeOfCollectionElements { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var collection = value as IEnumerable;

        if (collection == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var listToTestForUniqueness = CreateListToTestForUniqueness(collection);

        int countOfAllElements = listToTestForUniqueness.Count();
        int countOfDistinctElements = listToTestForUniqueness.Distinct().Count();

        return countOfAllElements == countOfDistinctElements;
    }

    private List<object> CreateListToTestForUniqueness(IEnumerable collection)
    {
        var listToTestForUniqueness = new List<object>();

        if (NameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness != null && TypeOfCollectionElements != null)
        {
// Trick 1

            PropertyInfo propertyInfoOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness = TypeOfCollectionElements.GetProperty(NameOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness);

            foreach (var element in collection)
            {
// Trick 2

                listToTestForUniqueness.Add(propertyInfoOfPropertyToTestForUniqueness.GetValue(element));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listToTestForUniqueness = collection.Cast<object>().ToList();
        }

        return listToTestForUniqueness;
    }
}
```

The Validation Annotation would be tagged something like this:

```
    [UniqueElementsRequired(typeof(Task), "TaskName", ErrorMessage = "Task names must be unique")]
    public object TaskList { get; set; }
```

If anyone can think of a more elegant way to solve the issue let me know, but it works so far.